# Is it halal or haram to earn money by watching and scrolling videos?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, money, game, gambling

Assalamu alaikum, there is a app where you can earn money by watching videos and shorts. You can search different channels and watch videos without watching haram stuff. You can for example watch food videos/shorts, islamic videos/shorts, flowers, animals ect. For every scroll you earn money and then you can redeem. Is this permissible?

Comment: Who pays, and where does the money come from? You might have heard of the saying "There ain't no free lunch".  Someone has to pay for it, and not without reason.

Answer (score -1):

Salaam,
It really depends on what you are watching and whether the content is halal or haram. For example, if you are watching an ad for a new prescription medication that will benefit users, then there is nothing wrong with that. Remember that Allah will lighten the heart of His believer who lives on Halal earnings. Hope that helps!
“Eat of what is lawful and pure in the earth, and do not follow in Satan’s steps.”
[2:168]
Best,

Comment: Assalamu Alaikum, thank you for your answer, the app I am earning from is an app you shearch diffrent people, for example Mufti Menk or Dr Zakir Naik.

Comment: In that case, you are fine:)